# Anneau vs bague?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Both of these seem to translate to "ring," as a piece of jewelry. When I put them into Google Image Search, *bague* shows me diamond-encrusted wedding rings while *anneau* gives me pictures of the One Ring from Tolkien's *Lord of the Rings* books.

Is there a well-defined difference?

Comment: Related http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/hibou-vs-chouette-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le plus simple à retenir :

> - Anneau : Cercle de matière dure qui a pour première fonction  d'attacher ou de retenir,

Bien sûr il y a des anneaux de toutes sortes et pour tous les usages...
... on parle même *d'anneau nuptial* pour dire que les époux sont enchaînés par les liens de l'amour... .

> - Bague : anneau que l'on met au doigt.

Les bagues peuvent se mettre aussi sur toute tige cylindrique (qui a la forme d'un doigt), lorsque la taille de la tige devient plus importante, on parle de *bracelet* ou de *collier*, toujours en référence aux mesures humaines.

---

*<sup>Références extraites du petit Robert</sup>*

Comment: Mais lequel est le plus précieux ? :-)

Comment: @Blue_Elephant ... l'invisible, le plus subtil et vivant à la fois : celui qui relie les souffles d'Éole autour de la terre :-) !